# GSuite Email Logs

Tags: gmail, google-bigquery, gmail-api, google-workspace

Is there a way to obtain GSuite Email Logs for a domain generally? I see that there is an Enterprise feature that allows for the export of email logs to Big Query. Is it possible to obtain the logs (doesn't need to be big query) for non Enterprise accounts? Or, if not the logs, then essentially the same metadata via an API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [About Email Log Search](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2604578?hl=en):

This feature is only available with the **[G Suite Enterprise](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7284269)** or **[Business](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6034782)** or **[Basic](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6047848)** edition.

> You can sift through the delivery logs for your domains and evaluate
>   message delivery using Email Log Search in the Google Admin console.
>   The reports help you track down missing messages, such as those
>   quarantined as spam or otherwise routed incorrectly. You can also use
>   the tool to determine message IP addresses and troubleshoot how
>   policies affect mail flow.
>
> The Email Log Search tool isn't available to resellers when accessing
>   a resold domain Admin console using the reseller console.​

Comment: Thank you @noogui! My understanding though is that the functionality is only available for Enterprise accounts and not Business or Basic edition.

Comment: @Andrew it is available for Basic too, go to admin console: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2618874

Comment: it's written there, G Suite Enterprise, Business and BASIC edition.

Comment: Respectfully @noogui, my understanding is that there is no API or way of automating email log search. Yes, you can search and obtain the last 1,000 logs and then export that to say a CSV. But practically that is different to the GSuite Enterprise / BigQuery integration as I cannot see a way to automate the extraction of all logs using email log search. But perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Thanks @DavidNajman. Please see my thoughts above about the limitations of email log search versus the BigQuery integration.

Answer (score 0):

The capabilities of ELS (Email log search) are very limited. The search doesn't support wildcards and yields a maximum of 1000 records. Who would expect a better search from google anyway?

Gmail logs in BigQuery is not supported in [Business](https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F9322135%3Fhl%3Den&assistant_id=generic-unu&product_context=9322135&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a).

The moment, when you cannot access your own data...